# unable to install web3 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ethereum, web3js

I am installing web3.js in ubuntu 18.04 with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g web3
```

and got following error:

```
> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
./configure: line 1904: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 1914: config.log: Permission denied


> scrypt@6.0.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/chakshu/.npm/_logs/2019-03-08T15_40_18_402Z-debug.log
```

Although `sudo npm install -g web3@0.20.7` works fine but I want updated web3.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Kashish Khullar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8276957/kashish-khullar), your solution works fine for most of the packages but not work when I try to install [drizzle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/drizzle). 
Now I found the root cause of this. I had installed the Nodejs with [binary](https://nodejs.org/en/) in my Ubuntu 18.04, which was showing the above error with many NPM packages like [Web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3). So I uninstalled both Nodejs and npm completely from my system and installed it again with the apt-get package manager, i.e, `sudo apt install nodejs npm`. Now everything works fine without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo npm install --save web3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Comment: yeah, it works. thanks.
p.s: to install globally and without keeping the record in package.json use "
sudo npm install -g web3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root".